# ASP Button isn't working when OnClientClick is missing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button

i generated a page with an ASP Button which loads another page.

```
<asp:Button ID="ServerCredentials" runat="server" Text="Server Credentials" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="12px" OnClick="Credential_Click" Width="135px"/>
```

Function which loads another page:

```
 Protected Sub Credential_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Response.Redirect("~/WebPage/Booking/ExchangeServer.aspx")
    End Sub
```

This code only works when i registered on the page with exchange data.

when i am not registered, nothing happens.

But if i put a onclientclick with any function, it works again. 
like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="ServerCredentials" runat="server" Text="Server Credentials" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="12px" OnClientClick="return CheckDateVonBis()"  OnClick="Credential_Click" Width="135px"/>
```

what is the difference between onclick and onclientclick?

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: OnClick is supposed to happen on the server and OnClientClient is supposed to call something on the browser (usually Javascript).  What do you mean by "registered on the page with exchange data."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onclick for server side function`  and `onclientclick for client side`

OnClientClick  : if you wish call javascript function

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.80).aspx

OnClick : if you wish call code behind function declared in server side

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick.aspx

Comment: thank you, is it possible that a function blocks the onclick function? because after i enter my exchangecredentials, it works again

Comment: i can't upload the whole code here, because it's too long. but is there any function or method which disables all asp buttons? then i could search for it

Comment: for example return false ; in javascript can disable your post, you can also have CausesValidation="false" ...

Comment: hey aghilas, i debugged the line where the button function is, i get this: <input type="submit" name="btnSerie" value="Eingabe einer Serienbuchung für den ausgewählten Raum" onclick="go_serien();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;btnSerie&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))"      i don't know if its helpful

Comment: happy that you solved your problem , i read your update, @Erat Please don't delete your first question , in order to save theses answers to stackoverflow, add your new answer in the end of your first question as addin (Or you can also create new question : best practise)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Response.Redirect you could try

```
Server.TransferRequest("~/WebPage/Booking/ExchangeServer.aspx")
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution:

i just need to set a CausesValidation on False to solve the problem:

```
 <asp:Button ID="ServerCredentials" runat="server" Text="Server Credentials" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="12px" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="Credential_Click" Width="135px"/>
```

i looks like that the site needs a validation to run the function